# Laravel - Eloquent - Get specific value from return array

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

I've following code:

```
     <div class="col-8
                    offset-2
                    mb-5
                    p-3
                    rounded-lg
                    shadow
                    d-flex
                    justify-content-between
                    align-items-baseline"
             style="background-color: lightgrey;
                 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.52), rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.73)), url('/images/social_{{$gallery->photos->first()}}');  ">
```

the part of the code `$gallery->photos->first()` returns:

```
{"id":3,"gallery_id":1,"filename":"IMG_3700.png","filesize":4229181,"delete":0,"created_at":"2020-03-28T09:56:31.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-28T09:56:31.000000Z"}
```

I need to access the filename.. I tried a few things, but none of them worked:

```
$gallery->photos->first('filename')
$gallery->photos->first()->get('filename')
$gallery->photos->first()['filename']
$gallery->photos->first()->filename
```

the last attempt (`$gallery->photos->first()->filename`) returned this error:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Trying to get property 'filename' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\galshare\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

how can I access the returned filename?

Thanks

Comment: what `$gallery->photos->first()->filename` returns? this was supposed to work

Comment: `Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'filename' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\galshare\resources\views\home.blade.php)`

Comment: This must work: `$filename = null; if ($gallery && !empty($gallery->photos)) {$photo = $gallery->photos->first(); $filename = $photo->filename;}` This has to work regarding first line of your shown code.

Comment: @Tpojka thanks, but how can I adapt it to enter it here? `.....social/social_{{$gallery->photos->first()}}');`

Comment: Please rewrite your question and include all relevant information. This what you ask now wasn't shown in question above. [Here is very good article of how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). It is highly recommended to read this article and rewrite your question accordingly.

Comment: @Tpojka done.. sorry, I thought in the beginning that i was trying to access the property wrong. Later it turned out I was doing it right, but the returnvalue is not handled well if empty data comes back.. but when asking, this was not clear to me..

Comment: I suspect error is from not well formed code in blade file. So try to deduct that part and post more than half line of code where error actually is. I think nothing is wrong with getting object but issue is more in formatting/managing variable in blade file.

Comment: @Tpojka Updated the post. I am trying to load a image as background in a div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210501/discussion-between-tpojka-and-sharkyenergy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some chat about this issue we came up with conclusion that `$gallery` sometimes returns an empty set which was reason for CSS rule to be angry (not having image URL in `background-image` rule). It was solved with one php block upfront where would be set default (fallback) image URL:

```
@php
$filename = '/path/to/default.jpg';
if ($gallery->isNotEmpty() && $gallery->photos->isNotEmpty()) {
    $filename = $gallery->photos->first()->filename;
}
@endphp
<style>
...
</style>
```

This block of code can also be done in controller from where can be sent `$filename` (i.e.) variable with value of `$gallery->photos->first()->filename || '/path/to/fallback.jpg'`.